# pubDate to unixtime in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time, rss

Does anyone have a function which can covert an RSS feeds pubDate to a unix timestamp? I tired using a javascript version of strtotime() but it never worked correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var pubDate = "Sun, 27 Mar 2011 20:17:21 +0100";

var date = new Date(pubDate);
var timestamp = Math.round(date.getTime()/1000);

alert(timestamp);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VDwVB/1/

Comment: +1, this is one of the few date formats that will be successfully parsed by all the major browsers.

Comment: There should be a second closing bracket after /1000

Answer (score 2):

Can be done easier using Date.parse:

```
var pubDate = "Sun, 27 Mar 2011 20:17:21 +0100";
alert(Math.round(Date.parse(pubDate)/1000));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to get the unix timestampt (this is time in seconds from 1/1/1970) it's as follows:

```
var myDate = new Date("Sun, 27 Mar 2011 20:17:21 +0100");
    console.log(+myDate); // +myDateObject give you the unix from that date
    console.log(+myDate + 60); // if you want to add seconds for example, you just sum the seconds that you want to add, since myDate is the time in seconds
```